# many-to many comparison of matrices rows in R

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe, apply

I am trying to correlate the data of 2 large data frames using R. The data are organized this way:

The first data frame includes ~5M rows. Each row needs to be compared to a few (i.e., usually more than 1) matching rows in the second data frame.

The second data frame is ~100,000 rows, and each row also corresponds to multiple entries in data frame 1.

I tried to use `merge()` to join the 2 data frames and perform the correlation on each row of the new data frame, but this results in a memory allocation problem. The resulting data frame is probably >50M row, which is too large to be handled.

Would you have any suggestion to do the many to many comparisons without having the generate a joined data frame? I had a look at the `apply` derivatives, but couldn't find what I want.

Comment: You could take a look at packages data.table and/or dplyr. Can you provide some code to generate sample data (of roughly the size that you're working with, if possible)?

Comment: maybe `sqldf` with or without the package `ff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge.data.table` function from the `data.table` package made the job.

Be careful to use the option `allow.cartesian=TRUE`, to allow the many-to-many junction, otherwise an error message is returned.